# Magento configurable product change details to show simple products details

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I'm trying to achieve something like this n a Magento configurable product:

http://shop.mdminc.com/c/sequence-pumps_sequence-titan

Is it possible? I need to change all the details of the page when the pump model changes. All details change from one model to another... Any suggestions or any extension. Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer,

I purchase this extension and with my buddies help we made it happen...

https://firebearstudio.com/improved-configurable-product.html

By default the extension did not change the sku and additional product information. Bu we made it happen...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension to show simple product information when selecte option in configurable product:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/display-simple-product-s-images.html